# Confluence table-plus rowStyles parameter examples

Tags: confluence

How to use rowStyles attribute for confluence wiki markup?
Could you please provide example?

Answer (score 2):

The table-plus rowStyles parameter is a comma separated list of styles. Each style is made up of one or more properties.

The first is applied to all heading rows determined by the heading parameter. The remaining styles are applied to the remaining rows in order with repetition as necessary.

Example: `, background:lightyellow;, background:lightblue;`

Source: https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TBL/Table-plus+macro

If you scroll down the page a bit there are several example tables with styles included in the wiki-markup. Hope this helps.

EDIT: Here is an example of how I added rowStyles in wiki-markup

```
{table-plus:border=0|align=center|cellspacing=0|cellpadding=10|class=''|title='Table One'|highlightColor=white|columnTypes=S,F,F,F|rowStyles=style="background:red;",style="background:yellow;",style="background:blue;"}
```

That should produce a table, titled 'Table One,' with the first row being red, the second row being yellow, and the third row being blue.

Comment: Thanks for your response but where I should paste them?

Comment: Are you using the macro editor or wiki-markup? In wiki-markup, you'll add the the rowStyles paramater followed by the comma separated style paramaters for each row. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: If you're not working in wiki-markup directly, then when you edit the table-plus macro you'll have to scroll down to the rowStyles paramater and add the comma separated list there.

Comment: That kind of markup do not work for me =( My confluence version is  Atlassian Confluence 3.5.13

Comment: @user590444 - the above requires that you have the Table Plus Macro installed, that's a commercial macro - https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TBL/Table+Plus+Macro